# How to find out how much time each user was logged in?

Tags: mysql, sql

How do I find out how much time each user was logged in system?
I have a table like this:

```
+----------+--------+---------------------+
| username | action |      timestamp      |
+----------+--------+---------------------+
|      111 | login  | 2019-01-01 16:00:00 |
|      222 | login  | 2019-01-01 16:01:00 |
|      111 | logout | 2019-01-01 16:01:00 |
|      222 | logout | 2019-01-01 16:02:00 |
|      111 | login  | 2019-01-01 16:10:00 |
|      222 | login  | 2019-01-01 16:11:00 |
|      111 | logout | 2019-01-01 16:11:00 |
|      222 | logout | 2019-01-01 16:12:00 |
|      222 | login  | 2019-01-01 16:21:00 |
|      222 | logout | 2019-01-01 16:22:00 |
+----------+--------+---------------------+
```

The output shall be something like:

```
+----------+----------+
| username | log_time |
+----------+----------+
|      111 | 00:02:00 |
|      222 | 00:03:00 |
+----------+----------+
```

If possible I'd like to know how to do that without using temporary tables.

Comment: What RDBMS are you using? Please tag your question with it.

Comment: And tell us what type your `timestamp` column is.

Comment: it's MySQL, and "timestamp" type is DATETIME

Comment: which version of MySQL are you using?

Answer (score 0):

This is the first solution that came to my head, I don't know if its performance is good.

```
SELECT 
    username
    ,sum(logout - login) AS log_time
FROM (
    SELECT 
        username
        , action_
        , ts AS login
        , lead(ts) over (PARTITION BY username ORDER BY ts asc) AS logout 
    FROM 
        'your_table_name'
ORDER BY username, ts ASC
)a 
WHERE logout IS NOT NULL AND action_ = 'login'
GROUP BY 1
```

Comment: I think this assumes that there is always a logout following a login.

Comment: It doesn't assume that, it will just ignore cases which don't have a logout.

Comment: To elaborate: This assumes that only a logout can follow a login (for each username), which may very well be the case, and is the case in the small data sample provided.

Comment: When there is something like login->login->logout situation, it will work as well. Of course, script do not check any possible edge case (I didn't think that this is a problem in this question)

Answer (score 0):

You can use LEAD for this in an inner query and then calculate the diff and a sum in the outer query

```
SELECT username, SUM(TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE, timestamp, next_action)) Minutes
FROM (SELECT username, action, timestamp, 
              LEAD(timestamp) OVER (PARTITION BY username ORDER BY timestamp) next_action
       FROM table) lead
WHERE next_action IS NOT NULL 
  AND action = 'login'
GROUP BY username
```

I did test this by adding a new login action without a logout and it gave the same result ignoring the new entry

Answer (score 0):

This will work for **MySql 8.0**, 
assuming that if there is no logout row for a user's login, 
then the current datetime will be used as logout time for the calculation. 
It will also format the result like `hh:mm:ss`

```
with 
t as (
  select t1.username, t1.timestamp login, t2.timestamp logout
  from logs t1 inner join (select * from logs where action = 'logout') t2
  where 
    t1.action = 'login' 
    and 
    t2.timestamp = (
      select min(timestamp) from logs where action = 'logout' and timestamp > t1.timestamp
    )
  union
  select t1.username, t1.timestamp login, now() logout
  from logs t1
  where action = 'login' and not exists (select 1 from logs where username = t1.username and action = 'logout' and timestamp > t1.timestamp)
),

r as (
select 
  username,
  sum(timestampdiff(SECOND, login, logout)) dur
from t
group by username 
),

d as (      
select 
  r.username,  
  r.dur div 3600 hours,
  (r.dur - ((r.dur div 3600) * 3600)) div 60 mins,
  mod(r.dur,60) secs        
from r 
)                     

select 
  username,
  concat(if(hours < 10, concat('0', hours), hours), ':', lpad(mins, 2, '0'), ':', lpad(secs, 2, '0')) log_time                 
from d
```

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/bW4NCrFcyysxHCLhmDmEFa/0)